# How to use caching in DependencyRegister(Nop.Web.Framework)

Tags: caching, nopcommerce

1) How can i use Caching in DependencyRegister.cs(Nop.Web.Framework)?

2) How can i get Current Login Customer in DependencyRegister.cs(Nop.Web.Framework)?

i want to current customer id using for Caching and when we use _workcontext for customer in DependencyRegister its give **Circular reference error**

please guide need help.

regards,
jatin

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you can't and you don't need it.

Dependency registration happens only on nopcommerce start-up.